# How to find which PayPeriodNumber it currently is, depending on PayFrequency in Java?

Tags: java, spring

Designing a payroll system in Java and have enumerated values for PayFrequency (weekly, semi, monthly, etc.). We are trying to figure out a way to ascertain what PayPeriodNumber it currently is, which hinges on what the PayFrequency for the company is set to.

i.e., if PayFrequency is monthly, and it is currently November, PayPeriodNumber is 11. This is quite easy for monthly, but what if PayFrequency is weekly?

Looking for a point in the right direction in terms of logic. We are using Java and Spring.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems rather a logical question not depending on Java or Spring. If `PayFrequency` for _monthly_ is defined by month's number, than for _weekly_ it could be the week's number (e.g. iso-calendar-week).

Comment: You first of all need to define your requirement much more precisely. On which day of week does the weekly or biweekly period change? If there’s a bit of a period at the start of the year, does it still have number 1? If frequency is bimonthly, does the new period being on the 16th of every month, or when? Etc., etc.

Comment: Which is your Java version?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 or newer, take a look at the new [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API. For the weekly frequency, you can find which week of the year a given date is quite easy. Assume you have the current year, month and day in the corresponding variables, then you can do this:

```java
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
int weekOfYear = date.get(WeekFields.of(locale).weekOfYear());
```

Or even easier:

```java
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
int weekOfYear = date.get(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

If you are using a version of Java older than 8, you can do the following:

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(locale); 
calendar.set(year, month, day); 
int weekOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use something like this

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // use this
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        System.out.println("week: " + week);

        // or this (Java >=8)
        WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
        int week2 = LocalDate.now().get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
        System.out.println("week2: " + week2);
    }
}
```